# `<firebase-auth>` not working on 192.168.0.x

Tags: firebase-authentication, polymer-serve

I am testing `<firebase-auth>` `signInWithPopup()` using `polymer serve`, everything works fine on `localhost`, but when tried from mobile browser via `192.168.0.x:8080`, it fails. Any idea?

Is that because I am signing in from `192.168.0.x`, and `<firebase-auth>` only support either `localhost` for local testing, or `https` only (which `polymer serve` is only `http`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it to work, you'll need to add in `192.168.0.x` into OAuth redirect domains' Authorized domain in [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com)